# Error occurred while generating PDF in Coldfusion using cfhtmltopdf

Tags: coldfusion, pdf-generation, coldfusion-2018

I am getting the following error using cfhtmltopdf:

> Error occurred while generating PDF. Reason: PDF conversion is failed due to timeout. Increase the timeout value in PDFgService manager settings.

According to these docs (see "Configuring the PDF service manager"), I should be able to tweek the PDF Service Settings in the web.xml file:
https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/pdf-generation-in-coldfusion.html

On Production, I am able to find the file and make these changes. It is located here:
//jetty/webapps/PDFgServlet/WEB-INF/.

However, locally, using CF2018 Developer Edition using IIS Server Mode, I cannot find any reference to any PDF service settings in any of the web.xml files in my CF directories. This folder also does not exist: //jetty/webapps/PDFgServlet/WEB-INF/.

I did find locally this folder:
C:\ColdFusion2018\cfusion\hf-updates\hf-2018-00003-314033\jetty\webapps\PDFgServlet\WEB-INF

There was no web.xml file there though, and adding one in with the settings had no effect (after restarting CF).

So I'd like to know how does one change these PDF settings in a local/development environment like this, like I was able to do on Production, in order to further debug this error I am getting.

UPDATE: We have logged the underlying issue with Adobe: https://tracker.adobe.com/#/view/CF-4208624

Comment: Is the service really available? Can you check in CF administrator under "Data & Services"-> "PDF Service"?

Comment: I think it could be that, while installing ColdFusion, you did not select PDF service. Please check if the service `ColdFusion Add-On Services` are there in the services list?

Comment: @RRK Yes, it is installed and is working. The PDF generation works fine when generating smaller PDF files. It's only with larger ones (for example 35 pages), that this error occurs.

Comment: We managed to pinpoint the underlying error with our hosts who have identified that this is in fact a bug with Adobe's code/application used to generate the PDFs and Adobe is now investigating. I will post the resolution (if any) once we hear back).

Comment: @PaoloBroccardo, can you post your solution of workaround of DOT NET app/service if possible? We still seeing this issue and still no solution yet from Adobe.